Number of unique ways to pick $k$ points on the $n$ dimensional hypercube graph up to isomorphism
Given an $n$-dimensional hypercube graph, I'm looking to find the number of ways I can pick $k$ vertices such that each selection is isomorphically unique.
So far I think uniqueness can be classified based on the distance between each vertex, so if we were picking 3 points on the 3 dimensional cube, there should be 3 unique ways, where the distance between the 3 vertices would be (1, 1, 2), (1,2,3), and (2,2,2).
The original motivation of the problem was to find the number of ways to pick $k$ points on the $n$ dimensional hypercube such that they are symmetrically unique, which should be an equivalent question. I thought putting it in terms of graphs may make be easier to work with, but I'd be happy to see any suggestions in either form of the question.

I think the original problem is easier, not harder; if I understand you correctly it ought to be doable with Burnside's lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma). I don't think the two questions are equivalent, since it could happen that two sets of points are isomorphic as graphs (maybe as metric spaces) but that there isn't a symmetry relating them.

This problem is discussed on page 112 of Harary & Palmer, Graphical Enumeration. Also consult e.g. OEIS A039754.
